# Shrinking effect of Tiles on ListBox on Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, silverlight-toolkit, itemtemplate

I've created a listbox like this

```
<ListBox Name="lstNews" SelectionChanged="lstNews_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <toolkit:WrapPanel />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="0,0,12,12"  Width="180" Height="180">
                                <Grid.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush>
                                        <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                                            <BitmapImage CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation" UriSource="{Binding Picture}" />
                                        </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                                    </ImageBrush>
                                </Grid.Background>
                                <StackPanel Background="#AA000000" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="70" >
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I need to add a shrinking effect when the user taps on an item. I've seen a lot of apps do that, I dunno how.

Comment: Do you happen to know of a free app that features this behaviour?

Comment: yea, most of them. the one I like though is the "BBC News Mobile" app

Comment: I just thought of it, would i get that effect if I add an empty context menu form the wp7 toolkit?

Comment: also check the "AppTracker" app please, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the tilt effect, which can be found in the wp7 toolkit.

You can set it at the global level by doing this,

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit" 
           toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
```

Some good [tutorials](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Silverlight-for-WP7-Toolkit-TiltEffect-in-depth).

Comment: Thank you!!! I was about to create a storyboard and start my own visual effect lol